# Add a new class with new protocol at runtime get different behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I found a strange issue in one of my projects. My goal is to add a new class with a new protocol in runtime. I took out the part of my code to reproduce this issue.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self registerClass:@"Daidouji"];
      [self protocolInClass:NSClassFromString(@"Daidouji")];
 }

 - (void)registerClass:(NSString *)className {
      Class superclass = (Class)objc_getClass("UIViewController");
      Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(superclass, [className UTF8String], 0);
      Protocol *newProtocol = objc_allocateProtocol([@"ViewController" UTF8String]);
      objc_registerProtocol(newProtocol);
      class_addProtocol(newClass, newProtocol);
      objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
 }

 - (void)protocolInClass:(Class)cls {
      unsigned count;
      __unsafe_unretained Protocol **protocols = class_copyProtocolList(cls, &count);
      if (count) {
           NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:protocol_getName(protocols[0])]);
      }
      free(protocols);
 }
```

In iPhone5(armv7) or iOS Simulator(i386 / x86_64), NSLog can print **ViewController** well. In iPhone5s(arm64), app will crash or print **(null)**.

The first solution I found, add **protocol_getName** like

```
 - (void)registerClass:(NSString *)className {
      Class superclass = (Class)objc_getClass("UIViewController");
      Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(superclass, [className UTF8String], 0);
      Protocol *newProtocol = objc_allocateProtocol([@"ViewController" UTF8String]);
      objc_registerProtocol(newProtocol);

      // add here
      protocol_getName(newProtocol);
      class_addProtocol(newClass, newProtocol);
      objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
 }
```

but why? Is there any correlation?

The second solution, found from my friend, add **__unsafe_unretained** like

```
 - (void)registerClass:(NSString *)className {
      Class superclass = (Class)objc_getClass("UIViewController");
      Class newClass = objc_allocateClassPair(superclass, [className UTF8String], 0);

      // add here
      __unsafe_unretained Protocol *newProtocol = objc_allocateProtocol([@"ViewController" UTF8String]);
      objc_registerProtocol(newProtocol);
      class_addProtocol(newClass, newProtocol);
      objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
 }
```

Once again, why?

I tried to found the difference between arm64 / non-arm64 in objc runtime source code, but to no avail. I hope someone can explain what's the root cause make different behavior. thanks.

update: direct download the demo code from github [RuntimeProtocolIssue](https://github.com/DaidoujiChen/RuntimeProtocolIssue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I post this question to apple forums. 
Glad to receive apple reply,

> This was a bug in ARC versus the Objective-C runtime. It has been fixed but I don't think any iOS release has the change yet.
>
> The safest solution is to call objc_allocateProtocol() and objc_registerProtocol() in a non-ARC file. Your unsafe_unretained fix should also work. Adding an extra call to protocol_getName() is not a reliable fix.

Wish to help somebody like me when meet this issue.